# registry key for file and printer sharing in XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, system-administration, server-administration

i want the where the XP  OS store the Registry entries for the file and printer sharing.

Thank You,

Comment: Why do you think this is stored in the registry? What do you hope to do with the values once you obtain them? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to Retrive it Programmatically,where its checked or unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

looks like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer` is where shares are hidden.
Unfortunately, I only have XP at work, and I don't have permissions to delve further